# How to give pdf.js worker in Angular CLI application

Tags: angular, pdf.js

I used pdf.js directly in angular app for some pdf purposes. It works fine.

I imported the pdfjs from the pdfjs-dist and my package.json includes pdfjs-dist.

My pdf is working fine, but in the console, I get the below error.

```
pdf.js:9067 GET http://localhost:4300/main.bundle.worker.js 404 (Not Found)

pdf.js:351 Warning: Setting up fake worker.
```

How to set up the worker properly in angular CLI application?

Answer (score 19):

I solved this by including the `pdf.worker.js` file in the bundle much the same way as assets are stored.

```
"assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets",
          {
            "glob": "pdf.worker.*",
            "input": "node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/",
            "output": ""
          }              
        ],
```

Then you need to

```
import * as pdf from 'pdfjs-dist';
// ... //
pdf.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'pdf.worker.js';
const loadingTask = pdf.getDocument({ data: this.pdfData });
```

Comment: I like this solution most,

Comment: This is the perfect solution in context to Angular.

Answer (score 13):

I solved this issue with some days of fighting.
First time I win with StackBlitz online Angular6 service. But had a problem with repeating at home.

In my case it is possible to use with Angular 6 and CLI with local file.
PS: Care about similar versions of pdf.js and pdf.worker.js (I use pdf.worker.min.js) when you use local installed and worker with external link like CDN and etc.

Got version I need from CDN https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/pdfjs-dist?path=build

Put your pdf.worker.js or pdf.worker.min.js to /src/assets/
And then use:

```
import * as pdfjsLib from 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = './assets/pdf.worker.min.js';
```

Specifications:
got with command 'ng version'

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.3
Node: 8.10.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 6.0.2

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.3
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.3
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.3
@angular/cli                      6.0.3
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.3
@schematics/angular               0.6.3
@schematics/update                0.6.3
rxjs                              6.1.0
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.8.3
```

Comment: I've been wrestling with getting PDFjs-dist working for the last two days, but using your example there is no `/pdf` in the `/build` folder.  Where you able to get a viewer that displays a PDF like the [PDFjs](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html) example?  I could really use a hint or example setting this up in Angular

Comment: You can see where is it in the Git repo: https://github.com/mozilla/pdfjs-dist
There is 'build' directory with files are needed. I have the same but installed with npm from pdfjs-dist (v@2.0.550).
Here is 'ls' command and I see directory 'build'
"~/Projects/NG_start/my-app/node_modules/pdfjs-dist$ ls
bower.json  cmaps     lib      package.json  web
build       external  LICENSE  README.md     webpack.js"
In the 'build' directory I have: pdf.js      pdf.min.js           pdf.worker.js      pdf.worker.min.js pdf.js.map  pdf.worker.entry.js  pdf.worker.js.map

Comment: How can you get this to work for angular-cli generated library?  Unlike applications, lib's don't have an assets folder.

Answer (score 5):

This is because you did not set the `GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc` property. Normally you set it to the URL from where the `pdf.worker.js` or `pdf.worker.min.js` file can be loaded. If you installed the `pdfjs-dist` packages it is in the same folder as `pdf.js`.

Try it out, as soon as you set the property the warning goes away.

```
PDFJS.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 
      "<your local path>./node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js";
```

In production you should load it from a CDN URL.

Comment: Isnt the worker already bundled and loaded by Webpack? So, using your example, it will be loaded twice (1,5mb time two)?

Comment: That was the only way I can fix the problem. Maybe there is a new version of the library available that solves the problem.

Answer (score 5):

The message "Setting up fake worker" means two things:

- Your PDF files are rendered just fine. Everything's working as expected.
- But the PDF files could be rendered faster. A lot faster.

The pdf.js library consists of two or three parts:

- pdf.js is responsible for displaying and managing the PDF file.
- pdf.worker.js is responsible for the core job of rendering the PDF pages.
- viewer.js is optional; it's part of the default PDF viewer.

If you load both pdf.js and pdf.worker.js by an `import` or `require()` statement, the core pdf renderer runs in the main thread. You can do better than that, and that's what the "fake worker" warning is about.

Do not load `pdf.worker.js` by an `import` or `require()` statement. The other answers have plenty of information how to do that. By default, this approach works out-of-the-box, but if your project has a non-standard folder structure, you'll need to set `PDFJS.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc`.

You'll be rewarded by a core PDF renderer running in a separate thread. More precicely, it runs as a service worker. Most of the time, you won't even notice, but if your PDF file exceed 100 pages or 100 megabytes, service workers make the difference between "too slow to be used" and "fast and smooth".

Let me conclude with some self-advertising: ngx-extended-pdf-viewer is a widget making pdf.js available to Angular without the pain. There are also some nice alternatives, such as ng2-pdf-viewer, ng2-pdfjs-viewer, and several others.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by using the pre-built version pdfjs-dist  and including the file pdf.worker.min.js in scripts

```
    "assets": [
      "src/assets",
      "src/favicon.ico"  
    ],
    "styles": [
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    ],
    "scripts": [
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
      "node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.min.js"
    ]
  }
```

then you shoud import the pdfjs-dist

```
import * as PDFJS from "pdfjs-dist";
PDFJS.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = "pdf.worker.js";
```