# Correct way to load worker pdf.woker.js in an Angular.io project,

Tags: angular, typescript, pdf.js

I'm trying to create a pdf-viewer component using Angular.io But i keep getting Warning: Setting up fake worker. What is the correct way to set up the worker thread in Angular.io. Both libraries seem to be loaded but pdfjs lib can't start the worker thread. Using the latest angular cli to create a project and components.  The latest pdfjs-dist library.

Angular.json

```
"assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/assets/helloworld.pdf"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js",
              "node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js"
            ]
```

pdf-viewer-component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-pdf-viewer',
  templateUrl: './pdf-viewer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pdf-viewer.component.css']
})
export class PdfViewerComponent implements OnInit {

  url = '/assets/helloworld.pdf';
  pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadPdf();
  }

  loadPdf() {

    this.pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js';

    // Asynchronous download of PDF
    const loadingTask = this.pdfjsLib.getDocument(this.url);

    loadingTask.promise.then(function (pdf) {
      console.log('PDF loaded');

      // Fetch the first page
      const pageNumber = 1;
      pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function (page) {
        console.log('Page loaded');

        const scale = 1.5;
        const viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

        // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
        const canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById('the-canvas');
        const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;

        // Render PDF page into canvas context
        const renderContext = {
          canvasContext: context,
          viewport: viewport
        };
        const renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
        renderTask.then(function () {
          console.log('Page rendered');
        });
      });
    }, function (reason) {
      // PDF loading error
      console.error(reason);
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to give pdf.js worker in Angular CLI application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49822219/how-to-give-pdf-js-worker-in-angular-cli-application)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49822219/how-to-give-pdf-js-worker-in-angular-cli-application