# How to add worker in ng2-pdf-viewer? can anybody

Tags: angular

By default the worker is loaded from cdnjs.cloudflare.com.

In your code update path to the worker to be for example /pdf.worker.js

```
(<any>window).pdfWorkerSrc = '/pdf.worker.js';
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems somewhat duplicated with [How to give pdf.js worker in Angular CLI application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49822219/how-to-give-pdf-js-worker-in-angular-cli-application), but here it's about [ng2-pdf-viewer](https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer) and the solution seems a little different.

I solved this issue by:

- installing [pdfjs-dist](https://github.com/mozilla/pdfjs-dist) `npm i pdfjs-dist --save` (maybe is already installed as dependency of ng2-pdf-viewer)
- adding pdfjs build files to the assets build options section in angular.json

  ```
    "assets": [
             "src/favicon.ico",
             "src/assets",
             {
               "glob": "**/*",
               "input": "./node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/",
               "output": "/assets/"
             }
           ],
  ```

  (Very similar as described by @stephan-rau in the documentation of [ngx-extended-pdf-viewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer#how-to-use-the-library))
- setting the workerSrc as stated by @graham according to the [ng2-pdf-viewer documentation](https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer/blob/HEAD/README.md#set-custom-path-to-the-worker)

  `(<any> window).pdfWorkerSrc = 'assets/pdf.worker.js';`